# Fixing debian installer

Tags: debian, install, apt, php

I have a VPS with Debian GNU/Linux on it. I'm trying to install a PHP file manager so that people could access it and download stuff into a directory.

I don't have anything in my /bin about PHP so this is probably an issue.

I installed PHP with this command:

```
apt-get install php5 php5-cgi php5-cli php5-gd php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5
```

and it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5 is already the newest version.
Package php5-cgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package php5-cgi has no installation candidate
```

It's saying php is already installed? I try to confirm this by typing `php -v` and it says

```
Command php not found
```

Why is this and how can I get php running?

Comment: What version of Debian are you running?

Comment: I tried your command using Squeeze, and I don't experience your problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Squeeze

Comment: What version of Debian is that? You might run `updatedb` and then `locate php | grep bin`, this should check if there's anything PHP-y installed.

Comment: @polemon  
I'm using debian 5.0 according to my provider but updatedb: command not found

Comment: Squeeze is Debian 6 and Lenny is Debian 5.

Comment: Show us the output of your "/etc/apt/source.list". While at it, do `apt-get update' and try the install command again.

Comment: everything in source.list is as follows `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free`

Comment: @tshpang `apt-get update` yields `W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security/dists/lenny/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving that comment to its own answer, looks like your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is faulty. Edit it to remove the line that contains debian-security, and replace it with

`deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free`

for the main distribution,

`deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free`

for security updates, and

`deb http://volatile.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free`

For so-called 'volatile' updates, then run `apt-get update; apt-get -uf upgrade` to bring your entire system up to date, and then try installing php5-cgi again.

(ETA: You can replace 'nl' with your own country code to get servers a little closer to your physical location and hopefully better download speeds)

Comment: I don't know which is which so I'm going to just clear everything in that file with what you provided

Comment: Don't clear it out, just insert a # in front of lines to comment them out if you're not sure you may need them later.

Comment: nice, thank you very much; I was able to updated to lated deb (i think) and i downloaded php fine with the command. However, it still says command php not found, do i need to restart my vps?

Comment: actually I'm not 100% sure if it installed, but I think it did`

Comment: The php command-line binary is in the `php5-cli` package, not `php5-cgi`.

Once you've installed `php5-cli` the binary should be in /usr/bin/php.

Comment: I just installed php5-cli but see no php in /bin.  Thanks a lot for your help by the way, I've been pulling my hair out over this for a while

Comment: `/usr/bin/`, not `/bin/`. 

And you're welcome. Don't forget to mark this answer as helpful once you've got it working. :)

Comment: yes in /usr/bin/ there is no php :( and just as a side note, squeeze doesn't work either meaning the apt-get updating didnt' work?

Comment: What, exactly, was the message you got when you ran `apt-get install php5-cli` ? Squeeze has nothing to do with this discussion; upgrading your distribution to the newest stable is another question entirely.

Comment: It is rather long but this is the output: `
http://pastebin.com/gVSEBege

Comment: For a long output you might want to use [http://pastebin.com] or something similar.

Comment: Okay. Like the output says at the end, you need to run `apt-get -f install` (without anything after it) to fix unresolved dependencies before you can install new software.

Comment: Another error :( `Need to get 0B/131MB of archives.
After this operation, 365MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on libc6
`

Comment: Use pastebin for longer errors, please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mC3s4tD5

Comment: ... Please tell me you didn't try to upgrade to squeeze while we were discussing this.

Comment: Try `dpkg --configure --pending` to see if that clears up the libc6 issue.

Comment: Someone above told me "While at it, do `apt-get update` and try the install command again." And I did try that, I did nothing with Squeeze. Anyhow, I entered the command `dpkg --configure --pending` and it accepted it and I `apt-get -f install` again but get the same error message.  Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure how you managed to trip that error, but try the following: `apt-get -f install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0` and see if that at least goes through the entire process without errors.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DtBKu9uy not sure if it worked but this isn't the full text output

Comment: Okay. Now `dpkg --configure --pending`, then `apt-get -f install` and you should be well on the way to clearing up those errors. (For the record, this happens more often if you don't keep your system at least _somewhat_ regularly up to date)

Comment: `dpkg --configure --pending` shows this: http://pastebin.com/ZFm2XYpg and `apt-get -f install` shows this: http://pastebin.com/nRUBBYEg

Comment: Okay. Now try `apt-get -uf dist-upgrade` and hopefully that'll resolve the conflict between console-utilities and kbd.

Comment: ok, here's the output http://pastebin.com/FAQvCzSi

Comment: Okay, try `apt-get remove console-utilities`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gPXKuWtS is what I get, I then try `apt-get -f install` and output is http://pastebin.com/HEVfZLRq

Comment: `apt-get -f install kbd console-utilities-`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UrtW1SK4

Comment: You left off the minus sign at the end of console-utilities. That tells apt-get that it needs to _install_ kbd and _remove_ console-utilities.

Comment: whoops, sorry.    http://pastebin.com/0gNYBtCx

Comment: That should have worked. Try in the opposite order -- `apt-get -f install console-utilities- kbd`

Comment: sorry for the delay http://pastebin.com/jjE8GkJj

Comment: @shadur Do you have any info on why this may be and what I should do next? Thanks :]

Comment: You're going to need to do something a little scary, I'm afraid. `dpkg --force-depends --remove console-utilities; apt-get -f install kbd` 

That will force dpkg to ignore dependency errors while removing console-utilities, which in turn will free up the conflict that keeps apt-get from installing kbd.

Comment: Here is the text output; still an error:   http://pastebin.com/HtTCb2y5

Comment: ... Oh, derp. That'll teach me to pay closer attention to error output. `apt-get -f install console-tools- kbd`

Comment: lol it happens :), http://pastebin.com/s2zGNA8d

Comment: ... Okay. Try `dpkg --purge console-tools`

Comment: :/ http://pastebin.com/iFEnX4dH

Comment: Okay, at least that's expected. `dpkg --purge --force-depends console-tools`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/V2TG0pwU

Comment: Okay. NOW `apt-get -f install` should fix the missing dependencies. Once that's done, another `apt-get -uf upgrade` to make sure you've got everything to the latest.

Comment: ok no errors this time :) http://pastebin.com/5ybgyKum

Comment: Okay. Now you should be able to install php5-cgi and php5-cli without further problems.

Comment: Thanks, it look like everything installed correctly when I did `apt-get install php5 php5-cgi php5-cli php5-gd php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5` and `apt-get install php5-cli` (no error messages) but when I type `php -v` in the command I get this: http://pastebin.com/grti6exe

Comment: That looks like your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file refers to a whole list of modules that aren't installed. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I have no idea :/ my vps came with preloaded stuff

Comment: so would php work now or is it still "broken"?

Comment: It should work now; Those warnings aren't critical -- although I do recommend you either remove the entries from your config or install the modules properly.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'll be online in a few more house to test it out

Comment: It still doesn't work :/ typing `php -v` should at least tell me the version number but it says unable to load library: http://pastebin.com/LE9hN86D or am I wrong? Sorry I'm so dumb here. How would I fix the modules or remove them?

Comment: It /is/ working. It's just telling you that a whole lot of libraries that its config files (`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/conf.d/*` ) want to include aren't actually installed on your system. You'll have to install them manually; the package names will likely be php-xxx where xxx is the name of the module (so php-curl for curl.so, php-mhash for mhash.so, and so forth )

Comment: Something is still wrong with my php. I have a file called test.php that has `<?php phpinfo() ;?>`. Instead of displaying the php file, it tries to download it. See here --> http://206.217.223.136/test/

Comment: That just means that apache isn't configured to use php - either via mod_php or via cgi. Have a look in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and make sure there are entries for php5 in there.

Comment: ah there is nothing about php in that directory, I tried `apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5` but don't see any changes

Comment: Well, actually since the main problem is fixed, I'll open a new question. My greatest thanks to you Shadur, you have helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Debian is that? You might run `updatedb` and then `locate php | grep bin`, this should check if there's anything PHP-y installed.

Also, check if your executable isn't `php-cgi` or `php5-cgi` (you need an extra package for the CLI: `php5-cli`).

In any event, tell us your Debian version.

Comment: -bash: updatedb: command not found

Comment: I'm using debian 5.0 according to my provider

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently? 5.0 is Lenny, but I still use that on several servers I haven't gotten around to scheduling a full upgrade for, and they have php5-cgi available no problem.

`shadur@mercury:~$ dpkg -l php5-cgi`

`ii  php5-cgi                    5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny9`
`shadur@mercury:~$ cat /etc/debian_version `
`5.0.8`

Comment: @shadur I ran the update and one of the messages that showed up was `W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security/dists/lenny/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]`

Comment: anyhow, i just want to install php :( I don't know why this is so difficult.

Comment: @kevinduke There's your problem - that URL is faulty. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and enter


`deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free`

For the main tree, and

`deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main contrib non-free`

For security updates.

Comment: That wasn't a command, that was an entry in a config file. See the answer below for details on what file to edit and what to put in it.