# Getting PHP to work with apache to run .php files through browser

Tags: debian, php, apache-httpd

I have VPS running Debian 5.0 (I think) and I would like to get it to run PHP files. I was told it needed to be configured with Apache. I tried entering the command `apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5`. But there was no change. Console output: http://pastebin.com/sVMWq6mA

This is everything in my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`:
`http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6474/modsb.jpg`

My webserver can be accessed here:
http://206.217.223.136/test/
In my test.php file I have the code :

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

but instead of displaying the page, it tries to download it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably missed restarting apache2...

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You will have to run this command from your root account, or put sudo on the beginning of it.

For full details on installing PHP5 - use the official php5 on debian instructions [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.debian.php)

Comment: Looking at the site you provided, I typed this: `vps:~# sudo a2enmod php4
ERROR: Module php4 does not exist!
`

Comment: @Kevin - php4 definitely won't exist, you installed php5.

Comment: I get the same error for php5 :/

Comment: And regarding your edited post, it says directory not found, perhaps I don't even have apache installed?

Comment: Ah, reinstalling just said they are at their newest version. Not sure why I don't have /etc/apache or /ect/init.d/apache2

Comment: @Kevin - a2enmod, a2dismod - enable or disable an apache2 module, you have it installed, but not enabled - What I'd try is removing php5 (apt-get remove php5 libapache2-mod-php5) then reinstall with apt-get install.

Comment: @Kevin - I hope that's not a spelling error? /ect/init.d/apache2 ???

Comment: I can't remove php5.... here's the console output: http://pastebin.com/H8ZMMQq6

Comment: @Kevin - ok somehow your module for php5 dissappeared, I suggest you [fix that error](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=30577)

Comment: @Kevin - if you have errors, most of the time a Google on them will help you solve them - ;-)

Comment: @kevin @palhmbus Given the ungodly mess that occurred back [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8455/fixing-debian-installer] I'm starting to suspect that there is something seriously screwed up about that VPS installation that's throwing out crazy error after crazy error...

Comment: @kevin One possible solution is forcing reinstalls -- `apt-get --reinstall install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5` and hope that that at least gets us a bit closer.

Comment: @palhmbus The link you provided didn't help either: http://pastebin.com/kDeKyAHV  @Shadur :( I don't know why my vps installation is so screwed up, when my vps crashed my providers said they had to reinstall the operating system

Comment: @Shadur It appeared to have successfully installed http://pastebin.com/KurVTqGJ

Comment: Also, it looks like apache is already running on port 80 but has not been started by the usual script. Try `/etc/init.d/apache2 stop` to see if it does stop correctly.

Comment: It looks like it stopped correctly `Stopping web server: apache2.`

Comment: @Kevin - on a completely unrelated note, why use PHP for a file server, doesn't ftp suit your purposes?

Comment: @palhmbus I have a really nice php file brower that allows multiple people to login and change things, ftp is less user friendly and presents a problem when other people go looking into stuff that's not theirs. I already tried jailing people in their directory but it just wouldn't work and I ended up screwing even more stuff. Anyhow I think the php filebrower is a win-win, I didn't know how much of a pain getting this to work would be. Anyhow what would my next step be?

Comment: @Kevin - your VPS is causing problems, either it isn't a very reliable VPS setup / company, I'd start from scratch with a complete reinstall of the VPS, I recommend you don't install debian (maybe their debian images are bad), try a ubuntu server, at least it would be simpler to get up. ;-)

Comment: :( I have lots of work saved on that vps

Answer (score 8):

Run below commands again and check...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 php5
sudo apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

Comment: I got several errors during the process, here's my full output: http://pastebin.com/2hmbC1Su

Comment: i have my php7 installed and it's not showing up .php files (running)